# C++ code breaks when trying to assign a value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, double-pointer

I am new to C++ and am trying to write code for a multi-dimensional array using double pointers. This is my code:

Class Declaration:

```
class magicMat{

    private:
         int** ptrnum;

    public:
        void init(int);
        void Display(int);
        void set(int);
        void message();
        void errorhandling(int);    
};
```

Function definitions:

```
void magicMat::init(int input)
{       
    ptrnum=new int*[input];

    for (int row=0;row<input;row++)
        ptrnum[row]=new int[input]; 

    for(int x=0;x<input;x++)
    {
        for (int y=0;y<input;y++)
        {
            *(ptrnum[x]+y)=0;
        }
    }
}

void magicMat::set(int input)
{
    int row=1,col=input/2,otherdiag=0;

    for(int value=1;value<=input*input;value++)
    {
        if (*(ptrnum[row]+col)>0)
        {
            row=row+2;
            if(row>input)
                row=row-input;

            col--;
            if(col<1)
                col=input;
        }
        *(ptrnum[row]+col)+=value;
        *(ptrnum[0]+col)+=value;
        *(ptrnum[row]+0)+=value;

        if (row==col)
            *(ptrnum[0]+0)+=value;          

        if (row+col==input+1)
            otherdiag+=value;                 
/*                                                                        */
/*       Determine where new row and col are                              */
/*                                                                     */
         row--;
         if (row < 1)                       /* If row exceeds side then   */
            row = input;                    /*  goto other side.          */
         col++;
         if (col > input)                   /* If col exceeds side then   */
            col = 1; 
    }       
}
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    magicMat newMat;
    newMat.message();
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>num;
        if (cin.good())
        {
            newMat.errorhandling(num);
        }
        else if (!isdigit(num))
        {
            cout<<"Please enter only digits"<<endl;
        }    
        newMat.init(num);
        newMat.set(num);
        newMat.Display(num);
    }
    cout<<"\nBye bye!\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works in the `init` function but when in the `set` function I try to check the value it breaks at the first `if` statement in the `set` data function.

Comment: Try just `ptrnum[x][y]`. If there's no real reason not to, use a vector of vectors instead. It's a lot safer. `vector<vector<int> > matrix;`

Comment: well i have been asked to use double pointers.This is a homework assignment.Sorry did not tag it as HW.Done it now

Comment: Incidentally, using an "init" function is generally against the spirit of C++.  Objects should be initialized through constructors--that way it's not possible to accidentally *forget* to initialize them.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: thnx for the comment.I will make that change.But any idea why the code breaks

Comment: It seems like you have out-of-bounds errors. Things like `col = input;` and then using `col` as an index when the indices go from 0 to col - 1.

Comment: I get a "Access violation reading location" at the first if loop in set

Comment: I would go through the function and rewrite it while keeping the bounds in mind. I'm almost positive that's the problem. If you have a `matrix[5][5]`, saying `matrix[3][5]` is not correct since it's 0-4, not 1-5. Your code is doing that, it's just a bit harder to catch.

Comment: its a C code which I am changing to C++.The logic is the same.It works in the C code.

Comment: If it works in the C code, you're just getting lucky.  You're indexing outside the bounds of the array and usually that will crash your program, but sometimes it won't.  It just depends on what happens to be located next to the array in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stepping outside the bounds of your array.  Just as an example, if I run your code and enter `5` as my first digit which sets the value of `input` to `5`, look at these lines at the end of your `set` function:

```
row--;
if (row < 1)
    row = input;
```

At the end of the first time through the loop in your `set` function, right before these lines, `row` is equal to `1`.  These three lines execute and as a result, `row` is set equal to `5`.

At the beginning of your next loop in `set`, you do this:

```
if (*(ptrnum[row]+col)>0)
```

The problem is that `ptrnum` is a 5x5 array, which means valid indexes are from 0-4.  At the end of the previous loop, however, you set `row` equal to `5` and as a result, you're indexing outside the bounds of `ptrnum` and thus crashing your program.

I highly recommend either stepping through your code in a debugger or if you're not sure how to do that, at least put in a bunch of `cout` statements in your `set` function so you can check that the variables are getting set to what you think they should get set to.

Good luck!